# Как сделать задержку при наведении, что бы меню раскрывалось после 2 сек?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/kyzjkb1u/

```css
#nav7, #nav7 ul, #nav7 li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav7, #nav7 ul {
  background: rgb(46,95,122);
}
#nav7 { /* подменю перемещается относительно меню */
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav7 ul { /* подменю находится вне потока */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
}
#nav7 li:hover ul { /* подменю будет показано, если курсор наведён на пункт меню с выпадающем списком */
  display: block;
}
#nav7 li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav7 ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
#nav7 .right { /* последнее подменю будет расширяться справа налево */
  direction: rtl;
}
#nav7 .right ul { /* для IE, решение найдено случайно, где связь ??? */
  right: 0;
}
#nav7 .right li { /* последнее подменю будет расширяться справа налево, но не пункты последнего подменю */
  direction: ltr;
}
#nav7 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav7 ul a {
  padding: 3px 15px;
}
#nav7 li:hover {
  background: rgb(96,145,172);
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav7">
  <li><a href="#1">Пункт 1</a>
  <li><a href="#2">Пункт 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#2-1">Подменю 1</a>
      <li><a href="#2-2">Подменю 2</a>
      <li><a href="#2-3">Подменю 3</a>
      <li><a href="#2-4">Подменю 4</a>
    </ul>
  <li><a href="#3">Пункт 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#3-1">Подменю 1</a>
      <li><a href="#3-2">Подменю 2</a>
    </ul>
  <li class="right"><a href="#4">Пункт 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#4-1">Подменю 1</a>
      <li><a href="#4-2">Подменю 2</a>
      <li><a href="#4-3">Подменю 3</a>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: я извиняюсь но вы делаете только десктопную версию ?

Answer (score 1):

Вставил в 2 места по нескольку свойств:

В `#nav7 ul` и так **же удалил** `display: none`

```
opacity: 0; /* По умолчанию скрываем подменю */
visibility: hidden;
transition: all .3s ease .4s;
```

Свойство `transition: all .3s ease .4s` добавляет анимацию на `0.3` секунды и задержку в `0.4` секунды

В `#nav7 li:hover ul` удалил `display: block`

```
opacity: 1; /* Показываем подменю при ховере */
visibility: visible;
```

Получается такой код с измененными блоками:

```css
#nav7, #nav7 ul, #nav7 li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav7, #nav7 ul {
  background: rgb(46,95,122);
}
#nav7 { /* подменю перемещается относительно меню */
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav7 ul { /* подменю находится вне потока */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0; /* По умолчанию скрываем подменю */
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .3s ease .4s;
}
#nav7 li:hover ul { /* подменю будет показано, если курсор наведён на пункт меню с выпадающем списком */
  opacity: 1; /* Показываем подменю при ховере */
  visibility: visible;
}
#nav7 li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav7 ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
#nav7 .right { /* последнее подменю будет расширяться справа налево */
  direction: rtl;
}
#nav7 .right ul { /* для IE, решение найдено случайно, где связь ??? */
  right: 0;
}
#nav7 .right li { /* последнее подменю будет расширяться справа налево, но не пункты последнего подменю */
  direction: ltr;
}
#nav7 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav7 ul a {
  padding: 3px 15px;
}
#nav7 li:hover {
  background: rgb(96,145,172);
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav7">
  <li><a href="#1">Пункт 1</a>
  <li><a href="#2">Пункт 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#2-1">Подменю 1</a>
        <li><a href="#2-2">Подменю 2</a>
        <li><a href="#2-3">Подменю 3</a>
        <li><a href="#2-4">Подменю 4</a>
      </ul>
  <li><a href="#3">Пункт 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#3-1">Подменю 1</a>
        <li><a href="#3-2">Подменю 2</a>
      </ul>
  <li class="right"><a href="#4">Пункт 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#4-1">Подменю 1</a>
        <li><a href="#4-2">Подменю 2</a>
        <li><a href="#4-3">Подменю 3</a>
      </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: мне понравилось но на мобилках работать не должно

Comment: @LenovoID да, мобилы её не держат это, да и на мобилах и не нужна такого рода анимация, отклик интерфейса должен быть моментальным.

Comment: вообще мне кажется ( только мой мнение ) что и декстопные версии и мобильные должны быть на jquery как минимум

Comment: @LenovoID не могу не согласиться, мой пример лишь добавление к вопросу автора, он не использовал js нигде, я показал что можно и так. А так по поводу js я с вами полностью согласен.